# How to specify a database on a Linux mongosh command line along with authentication

Tags: mongo-shell

I have a somewhat annoying issue that ought to be trivial but I cannot figure it out.  I am running on a Ubuntu Linux system (Focal); I have a mongo (version 5.0.3) database with authentication enabled.  I cannot find a command line that will drop me into the mongo shell for the database I want.  Could someone please lend me a clue?

If I issue the command `mongosh -u mongoAdmin -p '<password>' mongodb://127.0.0.1/` I get into the mongo shell using the test database.  To get to my database db-name, I need to issue the command `use db-name`.

If I issue the command `mongosh -u mongoAdmin -p '<password>' mongodb://127.0.0.1/db-name` I get an error message:

```
Current Mongosh Log ID: 617d0f78622b00d5095d474d
Connecting to:          mongodb://127.0.0.1/db-name?directConnection=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000
MongoServerError: Authentication failed.
```

Users I have configured in the admin database:

```
[
  {
    _id: 'admin.mongoAdmin',
    userId: UUID("6dbdd918-02c4-4000-b5e4-ff59db9f86ed"),
    user: 'mongoAdmin',
    db: 'admin',
    roles: [ { role: 'userAdminAnyDatabase', db: 'admin' } ],
    mechanisms: [ 'SCRAM-SHA-1', 'SCRAM-SHA-256' ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing piece was I needed to specify the authentication database on the command line.  This command works:

```
mongosh mongodb://127.0.0.1/db-name -u mongoAdmin -p '<password>' --authenticationDatabase admin
```