# How to Solve Authentication Failed When Connecting to MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, localhost, mongo-shell

I'm trying to connect to MongoDB using `mongosh` on the localhost, and when I type this command:

`mongosh --port <PORT> <DATABASE_NAME> -u <USERNAME> -p <PASSWORD>`

this what I got:

```
...
MongoServerError: Authentication failed.
```

Comment: Like nobody knows how to search over the Internet....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to specify a database on a Linux mongosh command line along with authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69778370/how-to-specify-a-database-on-a-linux-mongosh-command-line-along-with-authenticat)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Authentication failure while trying to save to mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb)

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem add this option and argument to your `mongosh` command:

`--authenticationDatabase admin`

So the full command will be like that:

`mongosh --port <PORT> <DATABASE_NAME> -u <USERNAME> -p <PASSWORD> --authenticationDatabase admin`

Comment: This is only valid when the user is created in `admin` database. It should be the normal case, however you can create users in any database.